# Clear Case Label Error

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

Applying label error

```
cleartool: Error: label type "label_1" not found in VOB "\newvob" and no global type definition can be found. 
cleartool: Error: Unable to create label "label_1" on "newvob" version "\main\12".
```

Answer (score 1):

This [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123179) mentions:

> **`cleartool relocate`** aborts with the below error when attempting to move a single element, `foo.c`, from a source VOB, `vob1`, to a newly created target VOB, `vob2`.

But if you weren't relocating a file, then it can be an [hyperlink issue between ClearCase and ClearQuest](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256278).

Or (if you aren't using the integration with ClearQuest): a [**broken hyperlink with the Administrative pvob**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21231183).
Check that last link first: it is probably the most common cause for this error message.

> - AdminVOB and its corresponding client VOBs are linked together using hyperlinks.
>     Note: A hyperlink also exists on the local copy of the global types residing in both VOBs.
> - Each VOB can only have a single AdminVOB.
> - An AdminVOB can be linked to another AdminVOB.

Step by step under the hood:

> - ClearCase looks in the current VOB for a local branch type definition (either a local type, or a local copy of a global type).
> - If it exists:
>     The client checks the parent global type for "process guards" (currently only used for UCM stream associations, but this check is made against all branch, label, an other types for backward compatibility reasons).
> - If no "process guards" are found, or those guards allow the branch to be created (checkout in UCM branch type in view connected to the right stream), the client creates the branch from the existing local type.
> - If a local copy does not exist, the client will look for an AdminVOB hyperlink.
> - If the AdminVOB hyperlink exists and points to an existing VOB:
>     the client searches that for a global type definition with the same name as the branch being requested.
> - If the global type exists, it will be examined for "process guards" as described above, if not, you will see the error in step 5 below.
> - If no "process guards" block the mkbranch operation, then a local copy of the global type will be made in the VOB where the mkbranch operation was requested and the requested branch will be created.
> - If no AdminVOB hyperlink exists, the client reports the following error:

```
cleartool: Error: branch type "{name}" not found in VOB "\mkvobtest" and no global type definition can be found.
cleartool: Error: Unable to create branch "{name}" from "." version "{parent version ID}".
```